# How to access my static ip from outside network?

Tags: apache, tomcat, server, static-ip-address

I bought a Static IP from my ISP, in router config in dmz i set  static IP to my pc ip (which runs an apache tomcat), I can reach the tomcat server from inside the network but it's not accessible from outside, what shoud i do?

Answer (score 0):

better than use DMZ is using port forwarding on your router. You can set only :80 opened and after this, it should be working.

Also, do you have your public IP configured on your router, or your router have on WAN port some internal IP of ISP?

If you have internal IP on WAN, you need setting up firewall rules to this WAN IP, not to your Public.

Comment: Your router must have also WAN ip, not only 192.168.1.11 (LAN network). Do you have properly setting of firewall on PC, where apache running ? For simply test, try to disable whole firewall ;-)